# API Key implementation in Apache Shiro

Tags: shiro, api-key

I have Java web application which implemented Apache shiro Authentication & Authorization.

Now i need to implement API Key to the existing project (which has apache shiro).
Please help me on implementation part. Even i could not find any documentation

*PS:: We have already implemented 3 different types of Custom Realm(jdbc,ldap,Pac4jRealm) but now struggling to implement the API key concept with Apache Shiro.*

Comment: Hi! SO has a great post on how to ask good questions, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Shiro's user mailing list might be a better fit for your question, as it sounds like you are looking for some general advice, and not a specific answer?  https://shiro.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Comment: Thanks @BrianDemers..but i am looking for any documentation which will help

Comment: Hi @mohammed, were you able to solve your problem? Three mailing list is still open to you and the result could be documented afterward. There is no documentation for this specific API KEY realm yet.

Comment: @BenjaminMarwell Yes i am able to resolve the above issue by using the JdbcRealm ( In doGetAuthorizationInfo method, extracting the API Key  and validating the api key against the db and allowing the user with the appropriate permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the above issue by extending the JDBCRealm,see the below example code

```
public class APIRealm extends JdbcRealm {
    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {

        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = null;
        AuthAPIInfo authInfo = null;
        try {
        String apiKey= (String) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal();
        authInfo=fetchAPIKeyInfo(apiName);

        // Do all the other stuff like checking for Authorization and setting it to token

        } catch (Exception e) {
            insertAPILogActivity(authInfo, "User not authorized");
        }
        return info;

    }

private AuthAPIInfo fetchAPIKeyInfo(String apiKeyName) {
    //Connect to Database using JDBC connection and validate the API Key and return the AuthAPIInfo
}

}
```

Add the above realm in shiro.ini

```
apiRealm=com.example.APIRealm
securityManager.realms=$apiRealm
```